# Jquery, error when using two scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

Im using two scripts on my website. 
This is for a sliding function between the pages.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#wrapper').scrollTo('#item2', 0); 

    $('a.panel').click(function () {

        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        current = $(this);

        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      

        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });

});

function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

    $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);

}
```

And this one is for image slideshow.

```
      script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"
```

When i implemented the slideshow the sliding function between the pages wont work anymore and it's because of the latest script. How do i solve this?

Comment: It's not the latest script. It's jQuery v1.5.2

Comment: Post the script for your image slideshow please

Comment: Not possible to see what you're really doing, but make sure to include a (newer) version of jQuery once. Then include your other scripts, without including jQuery more times.

Comment: don't include your second snippet.